How To Order Alphanumeric CharFields in Django
i have a model for menu items that has a CharField for the numbers as some of them have sub variants that have a letter suffix
fx. 25, 26, 27, 27a, 28...
how do i order the objects after the menu number with the suffix taken into account after?
so this list
[1g, 14, 2g, 27a, 27, 33, 33b] 
would be
[1g, 2g, 14, 27, 27a, 33, 33b] 
when just using order_by it defaults to the first number so
[27, 4 0, 27a] 
comes out as
[0, (2)7, (2)7a, 4]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would advise to keep the fields separate, this makes ordering a lot easier.

While you can do all sorts of string operations, casts, etc. this is not what databases are designed for, and it will very likely not work very efficiently because then it has to load all rows in memory first. Perhaps an option is to work with two fields, one IntegerField and one (possibly empty) CharField, like:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    item_0 = models.IntegerField()
    item_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)

    @property
    def item(self):
        return f'{self.item_0}{self.item_1}'
Here we thus separate the data, so for the sample data, it is:
data = [
    MyModel(item_0=1, item_1='g'),  # 1g
    MyModel(item_0=14, item_1=''),  # 14
    MyModel(item_0=2, item_1='g'),  # 2g
    MyModel(item_0=27, item_1='a'),  # 27a
    MyModel(item_0=27, item_1=''),  # 27
    MyModel(item_0=33, item_1=''),  # 33
    MyModel(item_0=33, item_1='b'),  # 33b
]
and then we can order easily with:
MyModel.objects.order_by('item_0', 'item_1')
as a general rule of thumb, you should see columns as atomic singular (flat) items. In other words, a single column should not store two (or more) entities of data, so not a list either.
